# How to prove this simple lemma "r^3=8 \Rightarrow r=2" automatically?

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to prove the following lemma.

```
lemma
  fixes r :: real
  assumes "r ≥ 0" and "r^4 = 16"
  shows "r = 2"
```

It can be proved by

```
proof-
  have "r = root 4 16" using assms apply(simp add: real_root_pos_unique) done
  then show ?thesis by simp
qed
```

or simply applying `using assms real_root_pos_unique[of 4 r 16] by simp`.

However, such prove strategy involves some arguments (e.g., [of 4 r 16]), and thus cannot well generalize to other cases (e.g., to prove "r^3=8 to r=2"). Is there a way to make this proof more automated?

I have tried some classic tactics, but still cannot avoid the need of arguments.